# Facet API : How to change some behaviors like having input radio instead of checkbox

Tags: 7, search

I need to change some default behavior from the facet API.

I am searching for documentation about the hook from the Facet API module, but I have not found anything for now, except a very good [tutorial about Apache Solr and Facet API](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/apachesolr-and-facetapi).

I downloaded the [Facet API bonus](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi_bonus) module because I thought it would help me.

There are some very good features like **Rewrite facet items via callback function**, but it seems it only works for the markup; I can't change the input.

```
function custom_facet_facet_items_alter(&$build, &$settings) {
  dsm($build);
  dsm($settings);
  if ($settings->facet == "field_produit_dev_durable") {
    foreach($build as $key => $item) {
      $build[$key]["#markup"] = drupal_strtoupper($item["#markup"]);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use the Devel modutle o see the content of the variables **build**, and **setting**, but there is nothing interesting for me.

[image: My facets now]

[image: What I want]

So I need two things

- Understand how to change the checkbox input
- Understand how to remove the count number aside the Yes or No

I made my module and use this, but weirdly it doesn't remove the number.

```
$build[$key]["#markup"] = drupal_strtoupper($item["#markup"]);
```

I used the fist tutorial I linked at the beginning of my post, but I found a problem I don't understand.

When I used my code on two different facets I got an error:

> An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.

My code is the same code shown in this [article](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/apachesolr-and-facetapi), but I replace the select field with a radio field. I think there is a conflict between the two form, when I validate.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing to change the markup should just *work*, here's a working example I have from a project that does just that:

```
function foo_facet_items_alter(&$build, &$settings) {
  if ($settings->facet === 'my_facet') {
    foreach($build as $key => $item) {
      $build[$key]["#markup"] = drupal_ucfirst($item["#markup"]);
    }
  }
}
```

I can confirm that it works as expected.

As far as switching the select for a radio, the error you get is pretty common and you're probably not removing/adding extra Form API options that aren't allowed for one of the types.

Radio buttons behave a bit different than selects, you might not be able to just switch the #type and have it work, if this is still relevant, please post the code you're using to alter that form... thanks!

Answer (score -2):

On this page you find a paragraph about creating a custom facet api widget:

http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/apachesolr-and-facetapi

Comment: This article was linked in the OP.